# Help needed with the use of FARSITE

Tags: qgis

Is there anyone who has worked with FARSITE?  I can build some of the files needed, such as slope and aspect, but not sure where to start when it comes to building files for 'canopy', 'fuels', etc.  I am currently using QGIS 1.8.0.  The tutorial provided with FARSITE is excellent, and I worked through that easily.  It's in creating the files for my area of interest that I'm encountering problems.  These would have to be created for South African conditions.

Comment: What is Farsite? I don't see it in the repository http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/?page=3

Comment: FARSITE is a fire behaviour and fire growth simulator.  You can read more about it here:  http://www.firemodels.org/index.php/national-systems/farsite
I think I should be able to use GRASS to develop the files I need to run a simulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canopy and fuel data must be obtained previously from fuel inventories or other type of information (conversion from land use data). If the data is in vector format, you just need to convert it to raster and then export it as ASCII (Esri-compatible) using GRASS module in QGIS, or GRASS directly. In GRASS you can use `r.out.ascii input=string output=string` (keep header information)